# Getting bad request response while sending data to server using the gprs connection in SIM 900

Tags: http, http-headers, at-command, gprs, sim900

I am trying to establish a connection with server using SIM 900 modem.

```
at+cgdcont=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com" OK
at+cstt="airtelgprs.com","","" OK
at+ciicr OK
at+cifsr 100.67.249.40
at+cipstatus OK
STATE: IP STATUS
at+ciphead=1 OK
at+cipstart="tcp","mydomain.com","80"OK
CONNECT OK
at+cipsend
> GET http://mydomain.com/test=vts
Host:www.mydomain.com
Accept:*/*
Accept-Language:en-us
Connection:Keep-Alive

SEND OK
```

These are the commands that I have used with the responses. Everything is working fine. But all i am getting from the server is a 403 Bad Request response. I have tried to connect with some other domains also. All of them are giving the same Bad Request response.

Is there any problem with the HTTP Header request I am using?

Answer (score 2):

The request line should end with a http version, e.g.

```
GET http://mydomain.com/test=vts HTTP/1.1
```

The syntax is

> Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF

according to [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).